# Not able to see Dicom Image on OHIF viewer

Tags: asp.net-core, dicom, fo-dicom

I am trying to integrate my own local server with OHIF viewer and it's sending a response to OHIF viewer till instances but it doesn't display images on Viewer and gives an error
Error Occurred invalid response: no multipart mime type header

I am using dotnet core for my server and sending image data as follows ( I am using fo-Dicom)

```
public async Task<IActionResult>Getstudy(string SUID,string SeUID,string img)
        {
            var folderName = Path.Combine("StaticFiles", "Images");
            var fileName = folderName + '/'+ img;
            string temp = ".dcm";
            fileName = fileName + temp;
            var file1 = DicomFile.Open(fileName);
            DicomDataset dataset = file1.Dataset;
            dataset.Add<string>(DicomTag.MIMETypeOfEncapsulatedDocument,"application/related");
            DicomPixelData pixelData = DicomPixelData.Create(dataset);
            byte[] originalRawBytes = pixelData.GetFrame(0).Data;
            return File(originalRawBytes, "multipart/related");

        }
```

I don't know if it's the correct way and i would really appreciate if someone helps me to connect my local server with OHIF viewer !!

Following is the error:

> index.umd.js?d226:9505 Error: invalid response - no multipart mime
>   header
>       at eval (cornerstoneWADOImageLoader.min.js?9f0f:2)

Answer (score 0):

It may be worth cracking open inspector and comparing fo-dicom's response with one generated by a successful request made from the OHIF Viewer's demo instance:

https://viewer.ohif.org/viewer/1.3.6.1.4.1.25403.345050719074.3824.20170126085406.1
[image]

FWIW, the default configured server(s) are implementing the DICOMWeb standard. [DICOMCloud](https://github.com/DICOMcloud/DICOMcloud) provides a .NET implementation of DICOMWeb (and I think it does so by wrapping fo-dicom)